# Reem Gazebo launch error

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-hydro, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Env: Ubuntu 12.04, ROS Hydro,

Followed the instructions on [Launching a REEM Gazebo simulation](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/REEM/Tutorials/Launching%20a%20REEM%20Gazebo%20simulation).

Installation went fine, but met with error while roslaunch

```
ResourceNotFound: imu_sensor_controller
```

Did

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-imu-sensor-controller
```

which solved that probem.
Later continued with Reem simulation

```
roslaunch reem_gazebo reem_empty_world.launch
```

An empty gazebo launches but without the REEM robot, and there is no file named 'gazebo-2*.log'

```
[ INFO] [1476515374.275733820, 8.382000000]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Path Constraints'
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ogre::InvalidParametersException'
  what():  OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Framebuffer incomplete or other FBO status error in GLFrameBufferObject::initialise at /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.4/RenderSystems/GL/src/OgreGLFrameBufferObject.cpp (line 280)
Aborted (core dumped)
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 19240, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode /home/josh/ros/reem-sim_ws/src/reem_simulation/reem_gazebo/worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/josh/.ros/log/48192e18-92a6-11e6-9d2e-80a589885b3b/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/josh/.ros/log/48192e18-92a6-11e6-9d2e-80a589885b3b/gazebo-2*.log
[spawn_model-4] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/josh/.ros/log/48192e18-92a6-11e6-9d2e-80a589885b3b/spawn_model-4*.log
[WARN] [WallTime: 1476515391.363697] [8.382000] Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface.
[default_controllers_spawner-5] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/josh/.ros/log/48192e18-92a6-11e6-9d2e-80a589885b3b/default_controllers_spawner-5*.log
Warning [ModelDatabase.cc:206] Unable to connect to model database using [http://gazebosim.org/models/cinder_block_2/model.config]. Only locally installed models will be available.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245757/reem-gazebo-launch-error/) by [r0josh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28227/r0josh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ogre::InvalidParametersException'
> ```

```
  what():  OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Framebuffer incomplete or other FBO status error in GLFrameBufferObject::initialise at /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.4/RenderSystems/GL/src/OgreGLFrameBufferObject.cpp (line 280)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

That points to issues with your graphic card (drivers). Gazebo is quite an intensive application.

What kind of system are you trying to run this on? Have you installed the correct drivers?

---

Edit: see also [Error in launching turtlebot](http://answers.ros.org/question/235211) fi.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1